# Is it possible to apply SELECT INTO a temporary table from another SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some performance improvements, I am looking at using a temporary table rather than a table variable

I am currently putting 100,000s or rows into a table variable using `INSERT INTO @table EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString`  (where @SQLString returns a string 'SELECT 'INSERT INTO LiveTable Values('x','y','z') build by dynamic SQL so that the x,y,z values are from the real records)

The `INSERT INTO` takes a bit of time and I was wondering if, having read about how much better `SELECT * INTO #tempTable` is, can you do a `SELECT * INTO` with another SELECT as the source?

So something like

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2)
```

Comment: What you have written should work, just as you have written it.

Comment: 1)SELECT  INTO #tempTable FROM Table2.
or
2)INSERT INTO #tempTable  EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
will hv to know whole story .

Comment: @GordonLinoff - When I try to run it as written, I get "incorrect syntax near )"

Comment: @Mike . . . You need a table alias at the end of the query.  So, `SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2) t`.

Comment: @newfurniturey - the duplicate you posted relates to MySQL, my question was clearly tagged as SQL Server

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thanks - the table alias fixed it. Could you post it as an answer so that I can flag/accept it please? Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your query is that all subqueries need a table alias in SQL:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tempTable
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes (I believe I have done this before, awhile ago, but I don't recall any issues). You can get some more information from this post on msdn:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92e5fdf0-e2ad-4f1c-ac35-6ab1c8eec642/select-into-localvarname-from-select-subquery

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2)T
```

---

```
   SELECT * INTO #tempTable FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable 
FROM table_name
```

**Yes** you can do this, Point to be noted is this  #TempTable  will be created on the fly, meaning if there is a Temp table that already exists using this error will throw an error as it will try to create a Temp table 1st and then insert the data into it.

To insert data into a table that already exist you will have to use INSERT INTO syntax, something like

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable      --<-- When using this syntax it is best practice to always
SELECT Col1, COl2, ....       -- mention the Column names in INSERT INTO and SELECT
FROM TableName                -- rather then using SELECT * to makes sure data is being
                              -- selected from and insert into the RIGHT columns
```

since you have mentioned you are using it with a stored procedure and would like to use make use of this syntax with store procedure, Im sorry you will not be able to do anything like

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp Execute usp_Proc
```

for this you will have to stick with

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable  Execute usp_Proc
```

The Temp table has to exists before you can insert data into it from a stored Procedure.